# Error deploying the switchyard quickstart in wildfly 8.0

Tags: wildfly-8, switchyard

'Hello, I am new to Jboss pardon me if i am asking silly question. When I am trying to deploy one of the wildfly quickstart example. But i am facing with this error. If anyone can help me that would be very helpful to me.
Thanks in Advance

```
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources,
i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ switc
hyard-bpm-service ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.20:test (default-test) @ switchyard-bpm-servi
ce ---
[INFO] Skipping execution of surefire because it has already been run for this c
onfiguration
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-bundle-plugin:2.4.0:bundle (default-bundle) @ switchyard-bpm-se
rvice ---
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.2.Final:deploy (default-cli) < package @ swi
tchyard-bpm-service <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.2.Final:deploy (default-cli) @ switchyard-bp
m-service ---
May 19, 2017 4:22:04 PM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO version 3.2.2.Final
May 19, 2017 4:22:04 PM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.2.2.Final
May 19, 2017 4:22:04 PM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 4.0.3.Final
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 51.304 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-05-19T16:22:06+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 73M/350M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:1.0.2.Fi
nal:deploy (default-cli) on project switchyard-bpm-service: Could not execute go
al deploy on C:\Company\wildfly-8.0.0.Final\quickstarts\bpm-service\target\switc
hyard-bpm-service.bundle. Reason: I/O Error could not execute operation '{
[ERROR]     "operation" => "read-attribute",
[ERROR]     "address" => [],
[ERROR]     "name" => "launch-type"
[ERROR] }': java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012174: Could not connect to remote:/
/127.0.0.1:9999. The connection failed: Connection refused: no further informati
on
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
```

C:\Company\wildfly-8.0.0.Final\quickstarts\bpm-service>'

Comment: It looks like the server isn't started. Did you start WildFly first?

Comment: Yes, James I did start the server before deploy

Comment: Can you post the POM configuration? It looks like maybe you've overridden the port to `9999` and it likely should be `9990`.